# SQL: How to query value in max datetime in each ID and fill null value with previous value

Tags: sql, presto

I have the Data in my Table.

[image]

I need current balance for each ID for each day(previous available value).

How to write such SQL query to get below output.
[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, because the two datasets look like they have about the same rows, but are different.

One way to get what you want is to use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a subquery for the balance:

```
select d.dte, i.id,
       (select t2.after_balance
        from t t2
        where cast(t2.create_time as date) <= d.dte and
              t2.id = i.id
        order by t2.create_time desc
        limit 1  -- fetch first 1 row only
       ) as balance
from (select distinct cast(create_time as date) as dte
      from t
     ) d cross join
     (select distinct id
      from t
     ) i
order by d.dte, i.id;
```

This uses standard/generic SQL.  Some functionality may be expressed differently in the database you are using.

Comment: Thank you verymuch

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff,  I found "line 3:9: Given correlated subquery is not supported"

Comment: @artpii I think you need to replace `order by fetch first 1` with https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#max_by: `max_by(t2.after_balance, t2.create_time)`.

Comment: @artpii when adding `max_by` did you also remove `order by` and `fetch first` / `limit` clauses?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I converted the query to `LATERAL` join first.

Comment: With a table like `create table t (id bigint, create_time varchar, after_balance bigint);`, the following can be decorrelated and is equivalent to @Gordon's query (almost, with the outer `FROM` simplified): `select d.create_time, d.id, r.balance
from t d left join lateral (
   select max_by(t2.after_balance, t2.create_time) as balance from t t2
   where cast(t2.create_time as date) <= cast(d.create_time as date) and t2.id = d.id
) r on true;`

Comment: @artpii: which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Presto